# AES Python encryption and Ruby encryption - different behaviour?

Tags: python, ruby, encryption, aes

From [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) site I have this code snippet:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
>>> message = "The answer is no"
>>> ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
>>> list(bytearray(ciphertext))
[214, 131, 141, 100, 33, 86, 84, 146, 170, 96, 65, 5, 224, 155, 139, 241]
```

When I take this array and turn it into a String in Ruby and proceed to decrypt it, an error occurs:

```
>> require 'openssl'
=> true
>> obj2 = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-128-CBC")
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x007fa388389b30>
>> obj2.decrypt
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x007fa388389b30>
>> obj2.key = 'This is a key123'
=> "This is a key123"
>> obj2.iv = 'This is an IV456'
=> "This is an IV456"
>> ciphertext = [214, 131, 141, 100, 33, 86, 84, 146, 170, 96, 65, 5, 224, 155, 139, 241].pack('c*')
=> "\xD6\x83\x8Dd!VT\x92\xAA`A\x05\xE0\x9B\x8B\xF1"
>> obj2.update(ciphertext) + obj2.final
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: bad decrypt
    from (irb):20:in `final'
    from (irb):20
    from /home/danyel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is understandably confusing—PyCrypto has gone a bit off the rails here and broken with the usual implementation. If you're familiar enough with what encrypted data should normally look like, the Python output *looks* blatantly wrong and gives you a place to start. If you're not, it's easy to wonder what the heck went wrong and have no idea where to start looking.

In a "normal" implementation, padding will be used by default and you'll end up (in this case) with encrypted output that's 16 bytes longer.

Encrypted using Ruby, for example, this is the result:

```
>> ciphertext
=> "\xD6\x83\x8Dd!VT\x92\xAA`A\x05\xE0\x9B\x8B\xF1\xD5f\xC7\xFFNI\xC7N\xBC-;!\f\xF1!\xB4"
>> ciphertext.bytes
=> [214, 131, 141, 100, 33, 86, 84, 146, 170, 96, 65, 5, 224, 155, 139, 241, 213, 102, 199, 255, 78, 73, 199, 78, 188, 45, 59, 33, 12, 241, 33, 180]
```

PyCrypto, for reasons I cannot immediately find, has chosen to [work only with unpadded data](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.blockalgo.BlockAlgo-class.html#encrypt). When interchanging data with PyCrypto, you'll want to configure any other libraries appropriately.

In the case of Ruby's OpenSSL library, the `Cipher` object exposes a `padding` property which can be used to disable padding:

```
>> require 'openssl'
=> true
>> obj2 = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-128-CBC")
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x007fe62407a9b0>
>> obj2.decrypt
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x007fe62407a9b0>
>> obj2.key = 'This is a key123'
=> "This is a key123"
>> obj2.iv = 'This is an IV456'
=> "This is an IV456"
>> obj2.padding = 0
=> 0
>> ciphertext = [214, 131, 141, 100, 33, 86, 84, 146, 170, 96, 65, 5, 224, 155, 139, 241].pack('c*')
=> "\xD6\x83\x8Dd!VT\x92\xAA`A\x05\xE0\x9B\x8B\xF1"
>> obj2.update(ciphertext) + obj2.final
=> "The answer is no"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great response. Do you know why this does not work with `AES.MODE_CFB`?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't. Any idea how to make this 'question' public (or bumping it) without creating a new one?

Comment: How could you go in the reverse direction from Ruby to Python. Python always seems to complain that "ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length"

Comment: To some people, forward is reverse :)