# Decrypt Data in Ruby using OpenSSL

Tags: python, ruby, encryption, openssl

I have the following code in Python that works well. It decrypts the data in the variable encrypted_data using the mcrypt module. I want to perform the same operations in Ruby. Therefore I required the openssl module. Unfortunately the Ruby version does not work. This is the error:

```
`final': bad decrypt (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
```

**EDIT**
I created a GitHub repository for you to test this. Download the sourcecode here: [github.com/ph3nx/ruby-decrypt](https://github.com/ph3nx/ruby-decrypt)

**EDIT 2**
The `bad decrypt` error does not appear anymore. I fixed this by setting `d.padding = 0`. Problem is: the decrypted data is still not correct. I can't view the image.

If you need additional Information about my system or anything else feel free to ask. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

**Python**

```
import base64
import mcrypt

encrypted_data = "placeholder: This is the encrypted data."

key = base64.b64decode("6vYJkO5beHNlwOm+aMqUTTzSpRw9jR3faHqu0wVoAG0=")
iv = base64.b64decode("EbuuKuVF4+DzDbWsvQi/ZA==")

m = mcrypt.MCRYPT("rijndael-128", "cbc")
m.init(key, iv)
decrypted_data = m.decrypt(encrypted_data)
```

**Ruby**

```
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'

encrypted_data = "placeholder: This is the encrypted data."

key = Base64.decode64("6vYJkO5beHNlwOm+aMqUTTzSpRw9jR3faHqu0wVoAG0=")
iv = Base64.decode64("EbuuKuVF4+DzDbWsvQi/ZA==")

d = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new :CBC
d.decrypt
d.padding = 0
d.key = key
d.iv = iv
decrypted_data = d.update(encrypted_data) << d.final
```

Comment: Decryption is not decoding. Ciphertext contains random bytes so it should not be converted directly to/from a string.

Comment: What is your encrypted data source? Is it from Python?

Comment: @owlstead Yes, you are right! The program derypts data. I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: @tsundoku The data is loaded from a different server. I don't know which programming language is used to encrypt the data. Why is this important?

Comment: There are a couple of settings to tweak, e.g. if you set `d.padding = 0`, from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661508/aes-python-encryption-and-ruby-encryption-different-behaviour

Comment: @tsundoku I tried to set `d.padding = 0`. Then the decryption completes without error, but the decrypted_data is different from the python version. I saved both files (python.jpg and ruby.jpg) the file size is identical, but the content is different and the ruby.jpg cannot be displayed.

Comment: @tsundoku I created a Github repo. The link is in the question. Please try it and tell me if you have any suggestion on what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found OpenSSL integration to be lacking in Ruby, and generally more cumbersome (uglier api / less convention over configuration) for cryptographic work then mcrypt.

If you're using mcrypt in python successfully, why not use mcrypt in ruby too? https://github.com/kingpong/ruby-mcrypt

Something in the lines of:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mcrypt'
crypto = Mcrypt.new("rijndael-128", :cbc, key, iv)
decrypted_data = crypto.decrypt(encrypted_data)
```

should work in your case.

I can extend on this answer later today or tomorrow, got some traveling to do first

Comment: You're a genius! This works exactly how I wanted. Do you know if there are differences in performance between mcrypt and openssl?

Comment: Lol thank you :) I'm glad it helped :) I don't know about performance differences, but they're all C-binded libs so mcrypt performance should be pretty good. We used ruby-mcrypt for encrypting some 10 million records or so in a live system with 700k users and we didn't run into any bottlenecks in performance there