# Encrypt String In Ruby and Decrypt in Python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, encryption

I am brand new to Ruby, so I apologize if this question is simple. I have to update a rails app so that it encrypts a string using a key. This is passed to an api written in django, where the encrypted string will be decrypted using the same key. I have the following code in Python, but I'm not sure how to encrypt the associated message in Ruby. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

class AESCipher:
    def __init__( self, key ):
        self.key = key

    def encrypt( self, raw ):
        raw = pad(raw)
        iv = Random.new().read( AES.block_size )
        cipher = AES.new( self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return base64.b64encode( iv + cipher.encrypt( raw ) ) 

    def decrypt( self, enc ):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc[16:] ))
```

Comment: i think it's really not that simple of a question to the everyday ruby user. Maybe it's easier to delegate the encryption / decryption to the underlying system (i.e. run shell commands). That way both Ruby and Python can use the same API.

Comment: The answer was updated and should fully answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

After feedback by ArtjomB I looked deeper into the proposed library. It is nothing but a thin wrapper around ruby openssl. So you can write a ruby version of your AESCipher on your own. 
It took some fiddling and research to find the right way:

```
require 'base64'
require 'securerandom'
require 'openssl'

class AESCipher
  attr_reader :key

  def initialize(key)
    @key = key
  end

  def encrypt(raw)
    iv = SecureRandom.random_bytes(16)
    cipher = build_encription_cipher(iv)
    encrypted = cipher.update(raw) + cipher.final
    Base64.encode64(iv + encrypted)
  end

  def decrypt(data)
    data = Base64.decode64(data)
    iv, raw = data[0..15], data[16..-1]
    cipher = build_decrypt_cipher(iv)
    cipher.update(raw) + cipher.final
  end

  private

  def build_encription_cipher(iv)
    OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC).tap do |cipher|
      cipher.encrypt
      cipher.key = key
      cipher.iv = iv
      cipher.padding = 0
    end
  end

  def build_decrypt_cipher(iv)
    OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC).tap do |cipher|
      cipher.decrypt
      cipher.key = key
      cipher.iv = iv
      cipher.padding = 0
    end
  end
end
```

In my testcases the ruby version decrypted strings encrypted by python and vice versa.

(i did one modification to your python code: remove the call to `pad` as I don't know HOW it pads. And just used strings that are length multiple of 16).

The answer by *colinm* in [AES Python encryption and Ruby encryption - different behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661508/aes-python-encryption-and-ruby-encryption-different-behaviour) was very useful.